# production is generating more records in test class, causing failed validation

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test, failing-tests

I created a Lightning Component Controller. It's suppose to clone our custom object `pba__Offer__c`. In our staging environment, I've managed to get 97% code coverage, and all my asserts pass.

Class

```
public class CloneOfferLEXComponentController {

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String serverCloneOffer(String offerId) {  

        pba__Offer__c  offer = [SELECT Id, Buyer_Email_Address__c, Buyer__c, Coop_Agent__c, Offer_Type__c, pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c, pba__Listing__c FROM pba__Offer__c WHERE Id = :offerId];

        String response;    // response after trying to save the cloned offer

        // if the offer doesn't have a listing, we can't clone the offer
        if(offer.pba__Listing__c != null) {
            pba__Listing__c listing = [SELECT Id, Auction__c, Bid_Coordinator__c, Stage__c FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id =:offer.pba__Listing__c];

            pba__Offer__c clonedOffer = new pba__Offer__c(
                Buyer__c                 = offer.Buyer__c,
                Coop_Agent__c            = offer.Coop_Agent__c,
                Stage__c                 = 'Pending Review',
                pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c = offer.pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c,
                Offer_Type__c            = listing.Stage__c,
                pba__Listing__c          = listing.Id,
                Bid_Coordinator__c       = listing.Bid_Coordinator__c,
                Auction__c               = listing.Auction__c,
                Recaptured_Buyer__c      = true
            );

            // this is done to cause the cloning to fail, for code coverage
            if(Test.isRunningTest() && offer.Buyer_Email_Address__c == 'fail1@email.com') {
                clonedOffer.Stage__c        = 'Reviewed';
                clonedOffer.pba__Status__c  = 'Subject To';
            }

            Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(clonedOffer, false);

            if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                response = sr.getId();
            } else {   
                String failureDetail;
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    String errorFields = '';
                    for(String eF: err.getFields()) {
                        errorFields = errorFields + ef + '\n';
                    }
                    failureDetail = err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage() + '. \n' + errorFields;
                }

                AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(failureDetail);
                e.setMessage(failureDetail);
                throw e;
            }            
        } else {
            AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('There is no listing associated with this offer.');
            e.setMessage('There is no listing associated with this offer.');
            throw e;
        } 

        return response;        
    }

}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class CloneOfferLEXComponentControllerTest {

    @isTest static void cloningTest() { 

        Account seller = new Account (Name = 'Test Seller');

        insert seller;

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'lastNameTest', Email = 'testBuyerEmail@test.com');

        insert c;

        List<pba__Listing__c> listings = new List<pba__Listing__c>();
        listings.add(new pba__Listing__c (
            Stage__c  = 'Pre-Auction',
            pba__Status__c = 'Available',
            Seller__c = seller.Id,
            pba__PostalCode_pb__c = '12345'
        ));  

        insert listings;

        List<Auction__c> auctions = new List<Auction__c>();
        auctions.add(new Auction__c (
            Auction_Program__c = 'Dual Path',
            Listing__c = listings[0].Id,
            Auction_Number__c = '5'
        )); 

        insert auctions;

        List<pba__Offer__c> offers = new List<pba__Offer__c>();

        // this offer should clone successfully 
        offers.add(new pba__Offer__c (
            Auction__c               = auctions[0].Id,
            pba__Listing__c          = listings[0].Id,
            Buyer_Email_Address__c   = 'succeed1@email.com',
            Stage__c                 = 'Cancelled',
            pba__Status__c           = 'Withdrawal',
            Buyer__c                 = c.Id,
            pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c = 100
        ));

        // this offer will not clone, because we are changing the stage/status 
        // in the controller.
        offers.add(new pba__Offer__c (
            Auction__c               = auctions[0].Id,
            Buyer_Email_Address__c   = 'fail1@email.com',
            pba__Listing__c          = listings[0].Id,
            Stage__c                 = 'Cancelled',
            pba__Status__c           = 'Withdrawal',
            Buyer__c                 = c.Id,
            pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c = 100
        ));

        // this offer will not clone, because it has no listing
        offers.add(new pba__Offer__c (
            Auction__c               = auctions[0].Id,
            Buyer_Email_Address__c   = 'fail2@email.com',
            Stage__c                 = 'Cancelled',
            pba__Status__c           = 'Withdrawal',
            Buyer__c                 = c.Id,
            pba__OfferedAmount_pb__c = 100,
            Offer_Type__c            = 'Pre-Auction'
        ));   

        insert offers; 

        Test.startTest();

        CloneOfferLEXComponentController.serverCloneOffer(offers[0].Id);

        try{
            CloneOfferLEXComponentController.serverCloneOffer(offers[1].Id);   
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Boolean error =  e.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION') ? true : false;
            System.AssertEquals(error, true);
        }

        try {
            CloneOfferLEXComponentController.serverCloneOffer(offers[2].Id);    
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Boolean error =  e.getMessage().contains('There is no listing associated with this offer') ? true : false;
            System.AssertEquals(error, true);
        }

        Test.stopTest();

        // should be the 3 original test offers, and 1 clone, so 4 offers total.
        System.assertEquals(4, [SELECT count() FROM pba__Offer__c]); 
        // on an offer, Recaptured_Buyer__c = true signifies the offer was cloned. There should only be one.
        System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM pba__Offer__c WHERE Recaptured_Buyer__c = true]);
    }

}
```

In production, the second to last assert produces 5 offer records, instead of 4. Any ideas why that is the case? It's obvious that my staging is not in sync with production, but I can't find the what is different between the two environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting a Validation Rule to prevent the cloning of the 2nd Offer:

```
try{
    CloneOfferLEXComponentController.serverCloneOffer(offers[1].Id);   
}catch (Exception e) {
    Boolean error =  e.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION') ? true : false;
    System.AssertEquals(error, true);
}
```

Check your Production Org for the Validation Rule and make sure it is activated.

Comment: Nice that was it! What is better way to make a record fail to insert/update? I updated my code to set a required field on the object to null during test.